# Email templates

Tags: resources, email

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but here goes -

I often find myself writing out emails that follow similar themes e.g. I've read through a document and have some questions, I'm asking for feedback on a proposal etc. Every time I write such an email I struggle with how best to express what I'm trying to say. Does anyone know of an on-line repository of sample emails that I could use as a starting template? I realise that I'll have to be careful not keep sending the 'same' email to people but I think the templates might help me get over the email writers block that I frequently seem to experience.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://www.savvy-business-correspondence.com/SamplesBizLetters.html) that I have used in the past to generate some e-mail templates. I ended up creating several as forms in MS Outlook. This link includes links to a few other collections, so you'll find several different examples to cover just about any kind of business e-mail you may need. (These are actually samples of business letters, but you can still modify them to create an e-mail template.)

Just in case you are interested, I am including a link to show how to [create e-mail forms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258256) in Outlook 2003. The process for Outlook 2007 is very similar. Good luck!